# When are the contents of .exit.text section in an ARM vmlinux file discarded once it is loaded in memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel

I understand that the .exit.text section will be filled by the linker with functions defined with __exit macro. I can see the section on dissassembly of the vmlinux file. But I did not understand at what point are the contents discarded once the file is loaded in memory? Does it happen in the kernel code? Can anyone explain this more?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files [vmlinux.lds.S](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S) and [module.c](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/module.c) handle this.  The handling depends on your kernel version and configuration; neither have been given.  My assumption is you mean the `.exit.text` section **in the kernel** and not some user space task.  Generally, the kernel doesn't exit, so they are discarded by the linker script unless you have some debugging configurations.

**Edit:** The android kernel was made with a `.config` file which enables Linux kernel features at compile time. The `.config` for **CONFIG_HOTPLUG_CPU** is a CPU; some big servers can keep running even when the CPU is exchanged. It is hard to answer your question. I don't know where your Android kernel source is or what `.config` options it was built with.

The sections are kept with `GENERIC_BUG`; so it is possible your kernel was built with this. From the stock *vmlinux.lds.S*, the `.exit.data` section is put **before** `__init_end`, so it is freed and returned to memory after the `init` portion runs. Ie, present only during boot.  Under these circumstances, you will see it in the *vmlinux* ELF, but not in the runtime *kcore* or however you are dumping it.

Specifically, [main.c's](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/init/main.c) `start_kernel()`, `rest_init()`, `kernel_init()`, and `free_initmem()` are the place where this stuff is discarded.

Comment: Yes I meant the .exit.text section in the kernel. This is actually the android jellybean kernel- Linux kernel 3.0.31 I believe. What configuration do you mean? Hotplug is disabled. I see that the content in vmlinux file's .exit.text section is different when I take a ramdump of the device (the content at the same physical address has changed). What changed this? Discarded during linking would imply that what I see in the statically linked vmlinux ELF file is already the discarded content?

Comment: Great! That solves it! Thank you.
On another note, the _vmlinux_ file also has a .head.text section at the start. This seems to be the kernel start up code, and the relevant code is in arch/arm/kernel/head.S. It has api's like enable_mmu, create_page_tables etc. As this is needed only at start up, why is it not discarded once boot is complete? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @piscianemperor  I don't know where/if the *head.S* is discarded.  It is a fairly small section of code.  It is all PC relative and can run at various addresses, afair.  It is in a different section, so _text/_stext can be used to discard/free that memory.